# Nested AWS Lambda resource UPDATE_FAILED due to the runtime parameter is no longer supported for creating or updating Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We have a root CF stack and multiple nested CF stacks which templates are stored in an S3 bucket. There is also a CodePipeline which is triggered whenever a repository containing the template files are updated. The CodePipeline uploads the updated template files to S3 and triggers the root CF stack and the nested stacks to be updated. Some of those nested stacks consist of Lambda applications which have some old runtime.

However, on the date when AWS stops supporting the runtime (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtime-support-policy.html), the CF stack failed to update because of the deprecated Lamdba runtime version. The root stack cannot finish the update rollback because the nested stacks failed to update but there is no way of updating the nested stack besides updating the root stack which is in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED status, and cannot be updated.

Reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-errors-update-rollback-failed, we know that we needed to fix the problem manually but we have no idea how to update the nested stack template.

Is deleting the failed nested stacks the only way to recover from this situation? If yes, do all the resources in the nested stack disappear after deletion of the nested CF stack? We are looking for a solution to update the nested stack and keeping existing resources intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-continueupdaterollback.html#:%7E:text=If%20none%20of%20the%20solutions%20in%20the%20troubleshooting%20guide%20worked%2C%20you%20can%20use%20the%20advanced%20option%20to%20skip%20the%20resources%20that%20CloudFormation%20can%27t%20successfully%20roll%20back.)

> If none of the solutions in the troubleshooting guide worked, you can
> use the advanced option to skip the resources that CloudFormation
> can't successfully roll back. You must look up and type the logical
> IDs of the resources that you want to skip. Specify only resources
> that went into the UPDATE_FAILED state during the UpdateRollback and
> not during the forward update.

There is a way to skip the failing resources i.e. the Lambdas in my case. This way, you can make the root and the nested stacks reach the `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` state.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: You can't do that!

Long Answer: You have to delete the stack. Update the runtime and any other required changes and deploy fresh. You might have to clean up resources which doesn't get deleted even after deleting the CloudFormation stack. Services like S3, ECRs, etc. needs to be deleted manually.